# Rails Active Model Serializer Include Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, active-model-serializers

Is it possible to include code in a serializer? I have some commonly used methods that I'd like to just include instead of always repeating them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for some code as an example:

1) Create your specialized serializer that will include the specialized concern

```
# app/serializers/specialized_serializer.rb

class SpecializedSerializer < DefaultSerializer
  include SpecializedConcern
  ...
end
```

2) Create your specialized concern in a new concern folder

```
# app/serializers/concerns/specialized_concern.rb

module SpecializedConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include SomeModule
    ...
  end

  def some_method
    ...
  end
end
```

3) Add your new serialized concerns folder to your applications autoloaded path

```
# config/application.rb
...
config.autoload_paths += "#{config.root}/app/serializers/concerns"
...
```

Comment: Note in Rails 6 you can add the serializers/concerns directory to eager_load_paths in config/application.rb with `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("app/serializers/concerns")`

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, you can. Either use concern, ApplicationSerializer, or compose another classes for sharing behavior should be okay.

Comment: Do you have an example of using a concern in a serializer? I've tried a bunch of different approaches and all have ended in errors.

Comment: I ended up making a new class called `FormSerializer` which extends from `ActiveModel::Serializer` and then I have my other serializers extend from it when I need forms related methods.